# How would I apply custom logic similar to "if statements" while transforming a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, logic, case

I'm trying to transform my data based on some custom logic. I'm a little lost on how to approach this problem given I'm new to SQL. Could really use some help on where to start, I'm comfortable with joins but the answer to this problem doesn't seem intuitive. I understand that the solution would involve using case when statements (for the second block of criteria below?) and doing an inner join on the first block of statements, but still a bit confused.

I'm adding a new column to my transaction data called 'difference_in_rate' which is the difference between a.rate and b.adjusted_rate. There is a pretty nuanced way to calculate this, please see the image below for the sample tables:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I need to apply logic such that:

1. check if transaction is between start and end date of helper table
2. check if product_id of txn matches product_id of helper table
3. check if growth of txn matches growth of helper table

Once these checks are in place:

1. if transaction code = REX, then rate associated with segment 1 is applied
2. if transaction code != REX, then check if duration >= 10 and if so then segment 2 rate is applied

Using this logic, transaction #1 would be linked to record #1 and transaction #2 would be linked to record #4 and the appropriate subtracted values would be inserted in the transaction table's last column. Thanks and let me know if I'm just speaking gibberish and need to clarify, first time posting here!

Comment: Hi Derek, can you put the data in that image as text in your question please? Will be easier to work.

Comment: Hi! I added the image in the body of the text, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to express your logic as a `JOIN` condition, using a `LEFT JOIN` in case there is no adjustment available and then `COALESCE` to set the `adjusted_rate` to 0 where it doesn't exist:

```
SELECT a.*, a.rate - COALESCE(b.adjusted_rate, 0) AS difference_in_rate
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.Date_of_txn BETWEEN b.Start_date and b.End_date
                  AND b.Product_ID = a.Product_ID
                  AND b.Growth = a.Growth
                  AND b.Segment = CASE WHEN a.Code = 'REX' THEN 1
                                       WHEN a.duration >= 10 THEN 2
                                       ELSE 3
                                  END
```

Output

```
Transaction #   Product_ID  Growth  Code    Duration    Date_of_txn             rate    difference_in_rate
1               ABC123      High    REX     12          01/01/2018 00:00:00     0.05    -0.03
2               DEF123      Medium  REI     7           12/01/2018 00:00:00     0.06    0.02
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=350f65bf95348537e472d54278443c7a)

Comment: So Store 1 has growth of both High and Medium?

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9b34c4ce6214e629aba5efd4763e2e11

Comment: sorry, store 1 would only have High. Updated link: https://imgur.com/a/vHFWoEU

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=ca6c471df337abb5bf1f423d0c965123 Note that product `DEF123` no longer has an adjusted rate since `tableb` only has an adjustment for `Medium` growth

Comment: You would just change the output values from the case to be the appropriate varchar values e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3ebf90a1ce04f71fda7ef89edf348877

Comment: The way they work is that the conditions are evaluated in order, so first we check if `a.Code = 'REX'`. If so, we return 1. Otherwise we evaluate the next condition. At this point, we know `a.Code != 'REX'` (otherwise the first test would have passed) and so we only need to check if `a.duration >= 10`, and if so, we return 2. The `ELSE` clause means that if `a.Code != 'REX' AND a.duration < 10` we return 3. `ELSE` clauses are optional, if not present and none of the previous conditions passes, the `CASE` expression will return `NULL`. Essentially it's like an if/elseif/else structure.